# Independence of random variables for jointly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

In our class, our professor told us that, the jointly distributed random variables are said to be independent if the following relation holds:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$

In addition to this, he said that when we define the region of integration we should be able to do it in a way such that x and y are not dependent. For example:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 6e^{x}e^{y}, x,y > 0$ are independent. But $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 6e^{x}e^{y}, x+y \le 1$ are not.

I am unable to understand why this is the case?

If I draw out the regions on a plane, they just look like two ordinary and similar regions to me,the first one being defined on a different range as compared to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x+y\le 1$, we have $y\le 1-x$. Given a value of $x$, the value of $y$ depends on $x$ with the constraint being $y\le 1-x$. So $y$ is in some way restricted by $x$ in this case, which makes it dependent on $x$.